# How to remove color from link when clicking another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

So my intention was creating a simple menu bar when clicking a specific link content related to that link was shown below. When selected the link'd get a blue color. I've created this

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>

a, a:visited { color:black }
a.link.active { color:blue; }

$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/gHb9F/
and it works but I want "link2" to already have this blue color when opening the window and changing it to the initial black color when clicking another link.

Comment: So change the class of link2 to `link active`? Since the active link relies on the actual page that is rendered, it makes sense to do that server side.

Comment: For anchor with text link 2, you can update your class from `class="link"` to `class="link active"`

Comment: You have a syntax error in `a.link.active`, should be `a.link:active`.

Comment: Your example works for me when I change the jQuery version to 1.11. Is there any reason you need to use 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire dynamically click event to the second link,

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.link').click(function() {
    $('a.link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }).eq(1).click();
});
```

```css
a,
a:visited {
  color: black
}
a.link.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>
```

Or add that class to the second link

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.link').click(function() {
    $('a.link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }).eq(1).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
a,
a:visited {
  color: black
}
a.link.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>
```

Or add active class in html itself

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.link').click(function() {
    $('a.link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a,
a:visited {
  color: black
}
a.link.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link active">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: @ThomasGijsels : GLAD TO HELP